# Edge Split Not In Edge Menu?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

I don't know why I can't find the Edge Split option in the Edge menu!  Is that option no longer available in the new versions of Blender?  I think I'm using 2.93 or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>M</kbd> > *Faces by Edges*. It's also on the *Mesh* menu.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: No problem. You're welcome!